# Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input', even doe the FormsModule is importet

Tags: html, angular, typescript, components, ngmodel

Somehow i get the Error 'Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input''.
Even doe the FormsModule is importet.

html (login.component.html):

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)] = "username">
<button (click)="login()">LOGIN DO</button>
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
ButtonsComponent,
ButtonPipe
],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
AppRoutingModule,
FormsModule,
FeatureEagerModule,
CoreModule,
HttpClientModule,
LoginComponent
],
providers: [LoginComponent],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Just to get sure i have also importat the FormsModule in the login.module.ts but even that cannot solve the error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your input inside a form? try this:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)] = "username" name="username">
```

You always have to put the attribute **name** with ngModel when it is inside a < form >

Answer (score 0):

LoginComponent must be in declarations, don't providers

```
declarations: [
AppComponent,
ButtonsComponent,
ButtonPipe,
LoginComponent
],
```